# Jenkins pipeline failure while executing test cases. "Jest encountered an unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Below is the detailed error log:

```
● Test suite failed to run
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/node_modules/pretty-format/build/plugins/DOMElement.js:26
  } catch {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.js:21:42)
```

Test Cases are running fine in local, getting above error while running in Jenkins Pipline.

Comment: Which Node.js version in pipeline running?

Comment: We are using node version 12.

Comment: Are you sure Jenkins is also running Node 12? Optional catch binding is supported from Node 10 onwards, if your pipeline is running a previous version that would explain the error.